# numpy.nan_to_num equivalent in sql?

Tags: python, sqlite, null, nan

I am trying to rewrite a set of python operations in SQL. Specifically, I have a python script that queries from a sqlite3 connection from a table `table_name` for the column `vals` and note that `vals` is a nullable column.

It then filters the return values using `numpy.nan_to_number` which converts `None->0` (NULL in sql) and large numbers to infinity.

Is there an equivalent way to do this as a SQL statement?

Comment: For `NULL` to `0`, [`COALESCE()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#coalesce), perhaps? For the other requirement, what constitutes a "*large number*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard approach for handling NULLs would be to use [coalesce](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#coalesce):

```
SELECT COALESCE(vals, 0)
FROM ...
```

---

Turning your large numbers into infinity is straightforward.

Let a "large" integer be a value with "more than two digits",
and let "infinity" be `99999`.
Then you'll want `SELECT ... CASE WHEN vals > 99 THEN 99999 ELSE vals END`.
Feel free to substitute a
[FP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity#Computing)
value if that better fits your use case.